# How to wait outside the loop without delay()?

Tags: serial, timing

Is it possible to delay a task inside a function that is called only once (meaning, it's not inside the loop) without using delay()?

[This library](https://github.com/kslstn/cozir) I'm using, for reading sensor measurements via serial has a delay() in it. I want to get rid of it, but I don't how to do it, because the library's function is not looped.

I guess the simple solution would be to move the library functions inside the loop, so I can do a simple check with millis() and run the delayed part as soon as 250 ms have passed. I would like to improve this library though and do a simple, single call for sensor data that doesn't not hold up the entire program.

This is the function with the delay:

```cpp
uint16_t COZIR::Request(char* s)
{
  Command(s);
  // empty buffer
  buffer[0] = '\0';
  // read answer; there may be a 100ms delay!
  // TODO: PROPER TIMEOUT CODE.
  delay(250);  
  int idx = 0;
  while(CZR_Serial.available())
  {
    buffer[idx++] = CZR_Serial.read();
  }
  buffer[idx] = '\0';
  uint16_t rv = 0;

  switch(buffer[1])
  {
    case 'T' :
            rv = atoi(&buffer[5]);
            if (buffer[4] == 1) rv += 1000;
            break;
    default :
            rv = atoi(&buffer[2]);
            break;
  }
  return rv;
}
```

I've had a look at the SoftTimer library, but it requires sketches to be written very differently (without a loop). I'm also not sure if I can even pass arguments to delayed tasks with that library.

Comment: The first question is: why do you want to eliminate that `delay` call? Does it harm your program?

Comment: Split the function into a `startMeasurement` and `readMeasurement` method. Maybe add a `measurementReady` method for checking if the measurement is done.

Comment: The sensor doesn't return data immediately and I use a pulsating LED to indicate certain levels. The delay disrupts the LED's smooth transitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split `Request()` into two separate functions: You call `sendRequest()`, then go do other stuff, then, some time later, you call `getResponse()`. If you get `RESPONSE_NOT_READY`, then you know you have to call it later:

```cpp
#define REQ_WAIT_DELAY     250  // Wait for 250 ms
#define RESPONSE_NOT_READY ((uint16_t) -1)

uint32_t time_request_sent;

void COZIR::sendRequest(char* s)
{
  Command(s);
  time_request_sent = millis();
}

uint16_t COZIR::getResponse()
{
  if (millis() - time_request_sent < REQ_WAIT_DELAY)
      return RESPONSE_NOT_READY;
  buffer[0] = '\0';  // empty buffer
  int idx = 0;
  // From here, same as original COZIR::Request()
}
```

This assumes that `RESPONSE_NOT_READY` (`0xffff`) is not an otherwise valid response. If all 2^16 values of an `uint16_t` may be valid, then you need another way for the library to signal that the response is not ready. Also, make sure you never compare timestamps, because of the `millis()` rollover problem. Taking the difference between two timestamps and comparing this with a specified delay (as in the example above) is rollover-safe.

**Update**: Here is an example of how this could be used:

```cpp
COZIR cozir(some_serial_connection);

void loop()
{
    static bool waiting_for_a_cozir_response = false;

    if (time_to_get_another_cozir_reading()) {
        if (waiting_for_a_cozir_response) {
            report_something_is_wrong("This COZIR is too slow!");
        }
        else {
            cozir.sendRequest("Hi Cozir! Pliz send me another reading.");
            waiting_for_a_cozir_response = true;
            /* We won't get the response on this iteration. *
             * We will ask next time.                       */
        }
    }
    else if (waiting_for_a_cozir_response) {
        uint16_t response = cozir.getResponse();
        if (response == RESPONSE_NOT_READY) {
            /* Nothing to do now, really. We will just try again *
             * at the next loop() iteration.                     */
        }
        else {
            waiting_for_a_cozir_response = false;
            do_something_with_the_cozir_response(response);
        }
    }
    do_whatever_else_has_to_be_done_in_the_loop();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure if I completely understand. In the example getResponse() is not called. I could put a call in the loop, but I'd prefer not to.

I tried the code as proposed and it compiles, but now I don't get sensor measurements returned any longer with czr.Celsius();

Comment: Yes, you have have to call `getResponse()` in the loop, see updated answer. Why do you want to avoid it? Here is the deal: You send a request to the Cozir, but it is slow to respond. You have three choices: 1) you just wait: that's the cozir lib approach 2) yo go do your business, but you remember you have to come later see whether the answer is ready: that's the code I gave you 3) you go do your business, and have something interrupt you and tell you it's time to get the response: that's the SoftTimer approach. Now it's time for you to make a choice: which approach do you prefer?

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification, this was exactly what I was wondering about, as I didn't know the options. I will probably go with your second option with the code you provided. That way I don't have to rewrite the sketch completely. For a next project I will probably use SoftTimer though.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the BlinkWithoutDelay example sketch (under Digital).  Basically you store the current millis as a variable, then have an if statement to check that it has been more than x milliseconds.

Comment: I would still have to put that inside the loop.